# ngx pie chart - unable to access input data inside labelFormatting

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I'm failing to access my `portfolio` input property inside the `labelFormatting` method.

I need this portfolio data in order to calculate the sum, so as to format the label data into percentages.

The problem I'm facing is that the `portfolio` object is persistently `undefined` when called within the context of the `labelFormatting`. I'm assuming this happens because this method is called before the input property is ready, when the chart is first created.

Here is my component:

```
export class PortfolioPreviewCardComponent {
    @Input() portfolio!: IPortfolio;
    data = [...];

    // options
    showLegend = false;
    showLabels = true;
    isDoughnut = true;

    ...
    ...
    ...

    labelFormatting(name: string) { // this name will contain the name you defined in chartData[]
        const self: any = this; // this "this" will refer to the chart component
        const data: DataItem[] = self.series.filter((x: { name: string }) => x.name == name);
    
        // portfolio is undefined here
        const sum = this.portfolio.holdings.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
            return accumulator + item.total;
        }, 0);

        if(data.length > 0) {
            return (((data[0].value / sum) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        } else {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the template:

```
<ngx-charts-pie-chart
        *ngIf="portfolio"
        scheme="cool"
        [results]="data"
        [legend]="showLegend"
        [labels]="showLabels"
        [doughnut]="isDoughnut"
        [labelFormatting]="labelFormatting"
        (select)="onSelect($event)"
        (activate)="onActivate($event)"
        (deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)"
>
</ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mananged to find a solution where I explicitly set the `labelFormatting` function of the chart in the `AfterViewInit` hook, like so:

```
@ViewChild('pieChart') pieChart!: PieChartComponent; // template chart reference
...
...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.pieChart) {
        // used a chartManager service to deal with the labelFormatting logic
        this.pieChart.labelFormatting = (name: string) => this.chartManager.labelFormatting(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you commented in your code, `this` is the chart in your handler. Perhaps you should just return a function to keep your component instance in a closure?

```
labelFormatting() {
    const myComponent = this;
    return (name: string) => {
        const data: DataItem[] = this.series.filter((x: { name: string }) => x.name == name);

        const sum = myComponent.portfolio.holdings.reduce((accumulator, item) => accumulator + item.total, 0);

        if (data.length > 0) {
            return (((data[0].value / sum) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        }

        return name;
    }
}
```

The your attribute should be like this:

```
<ngx-charts-pie-chart
    [labelFormatting]="labelFormatting()"></ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Meanwhile I found a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76970460/15822615).